# I am not able to get data from my localhost using this code. Please help me. I am getting nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)
println(data)
```

After using this line of code in playground I am getting nil value for data. So how do I get a value.

My real URL is: `192.168.1.8:8888/service.php` (this url is showing JSON data in the browser)

But I am not able to get data from the url 
Please help me.

Comment: You need to add `http://` or some other appropriate scheme to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in full URL

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.8:8888/service.php")!)
println(data)
```